# Printing symbols after random function

Tags: c, random

I made a program that involves a lot of randomization.

It all works fine, except for array number 5 `char a5`, which includes 2 strings. There's a 5% chance of any of them appearing.

Once I execute my program, random symbols appear once in a while, if I launch it enough times, I hear the "Critical stop" error sound but no visible error.

My program has an input loop to prevent me from launching it again, which I'll keep here for ease of use.

**Here's the minimal code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

main(){
    srand (time(NULL));
    int j, v;
    char i, mlt [6], a5[2][6] = {" x2", " x3"}; 
    do{ 
    system ("cls");
        for (j=0; j<10; j++){
            
            v = rand () % 95;
            char* b4[6] = {a5[v]};
            char mik[10] = (" ");
            
            strcpy (mlt, mik);
            strcat (mlt, *b4);
            printf (" %s\n", mlt);
        }
    printf ("Press 'n' to exit... ");
    scanf (" %s", &i);
    }
    while (i!='n' && i!='N');
}
```

Here's a screensnip example of a random launch (on my normal program):

[image: output of normal code and a symbol]

Comment: Your code does not compile and has many warnings. https://ideone.com/7oU7FN The most common reason for an issue like this is failure to properly terminate a string, often because the destination buffer is not large enough.

Comment: I fixed the problem. There were some leftovers from the main program

Comment: It also prints "old" and "ot" on the main program, which are array3 partial strings (Cold, Hot)

And without `char mik[10] = (" ");` it just prints gibberish like  "í&rg°⌂♦y▼" without changing

Comment: Including `windows.h` to avoid including `string.h` is a bit of overkill. `scanf (" %s", &i);` is incorrect because the argument is a pointer to a single character not an array capable of handling the input and the terminating 0. `a5` contains 2 strings, but `v` can be 0 to 94 which will access the array way out of bounds.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions; I will use them from now on. I only know the basics of C and never learned some things before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two major issues:

1. `scanf (" %s", &i);` will lead to buffer overflow for any input besides enter.
2. `int v = rand () % 95` will yield a number between 0 and 94, yet you use `v` to index into `a5` which is out of bounds for `v > 1`.

Other minor issues:

3. `i` is usually a integer loop variable, not wrong, but I changed it to `c`.
4. Reduce scope of variables and consider eliminating the ones you don't really need.
5. The correct declaration for main is `int main(void)` (or `int main(int, char **)`.

Here is how I modified your program:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(;;) {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            printf("   x%d\n", (rand() % 2) + 2);
        }
        printf ("Press 'n' to exit... ");
        char c;
        if(!scanf("%c", &c) || toupper(c) == 'N')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what I could've improved on. However, I do not want the program to print the "x2" or "x3" every time. That's why I used the `rand() % 95` for a 5% chance. I am currently looking into using another alternative to an array.

Comment: I agree and I apologize. I am new here and am not familiar with the voting system and personally, don't know when it's appropriate to vote.
When it comes to the program, I opted to ditch the array, which fixed the issue.

Comment: Nothing to apologize for just trying to help you make the best use of this community.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Fixed.  That would be signal that it's getting too late to answer questions for tonight :-)